# How to get the size of the image selected from gallery in Android?

Tags: android

I am doing a Android project in which, i have to take picture using camera or from gallery.

Normally when we do this, we get the URL of the image and i got it. But let me know is there any way to get the size of the image that we are selecting from that gallery programatically?

Can anyone suggest a solution or if you know any useful link related to this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(filePathOfSelectedImage), null, null);
```

Now you can get the height and width by using **getHeight()** and **getWidth()** method of bitmap.

Answer (score 1):

The determine the size of a bitmap object use [getRowBytes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getRowBytes%28%29)

```
Bitmap image = ..
final int sizeInBytes = image.getHeight() * image.getRowBytes();
```

Since API level 12 you can use [getByteCount()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#getByteCount%28%29) instead

```
final int sizeInBytes = image.getByteCount();
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your image into a `Bitmap` object, then use `getWidth()`, `getHeight()` methods of Bitmap object to get the size of image.

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
int w = image.getWidth();
int h = image.getHeight();
```

Comment: From this how we can find the image size? Will width*height will be same as  image size?

Comment: Ah, sorry. When you refered to size I understood the height and width. But if you meant the size of the image in bytes, megabytes, etc... then an idea is to covert the bitmap to a byte[] array. Or, if you are extracting the images directly from the gallery with a Cursor, you could access the size of the image from the android.provider.MediaStore.MediaColumns - SIZE column.